# Webpack rendering sass, babel and es2015 - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, babeljs

I want to configure webpack to render es15, react and sass.

After i added code for sass loading I get following message:

```
ERROR in ./src/app.jsx
Module parse failed: /home/giedrius/projects/react-redux/react-redux-seed/src/app.jsx Unexpected token (7:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| class App extends React.Component {
|   render () {
|     return <Header/>;
|   }
| }
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8085 ./src/app.jsx
```

My webpack config looks like this:

```
const path = require('path'); 
let webpack = require('webpack');
let ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

    module.exports = {
         entry: './src/app.jsx',
         output: {
             path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'js'),
             filename: 'app.bundle.js'
         },
         resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
         },
         module: {
             loaders: [
                {
                    test: /.jsx?$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    options: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }
                }
              ],
                rules: [
                  {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                      fallback: 'style-loader',
                      use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                    })
                  }
                ]
      },
      plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("public/css/styles.css"),
      ]

     };
```

Server is starting and showing header, so unsure why is this message is appearing. Anyone had similar issues ?

The code that was added was rules and plugin array.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have both loaders and rules, they are basically the same thing. Loaders was renamed to rules. You should have only one of them.

Check this for more info: https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules

Try this:

```js
module: {
  rules: [{
      test: /.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      options: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      })
    }
  ]
}
```